# Turn on driving mode on any android phone

Tags: android

Is it possible to enable a driving mode like that found on the Galaxy S phones when the user presses a button?
Or is this not built into all android phones?

Comment: You might wish to explain, in greater detail, what "a driving mode" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such a "mode" using Tasker (found in the Play Store).  Basically you set up actions that occur based on certain events (such as a button press).  Actions include changing brightness/volume settings, triggering apps etc...

For example, I created a button that sets me "Available"/"Unavailale" for phone calls - it doesn't just turn the ringer off, it shoots the callers right to VM...

It takes a bit of work (and isn't free), but Tasker is pretty powerful & you can typically find help online fairly easily.